# css dropdown menu issue on small device

Tags: jquery, css-position, fixed

I am trying to have a fix menu on my iPhone media query. This is working as its suppose to as long as I clickthe menu when its on the top of the page, but as soon as I scroll down the page and then click on the menu, it doesn't fold out properly until I scroll back at the top of the page again.
It works normally on all other media queries except for the media query 480px and below. This is the [sample page](http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/Index.html).

-Sohail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to set the z-index on .menu-button

```
.menu-button {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: block;
padding: 1em;
background: #ff8400;
color: #222222;
cursor: pointer;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: 99; <-- HERE
}
```

Additionally you will want to alter your margin to move your first menu item 'blog' below the new top Menu li

**Update:**
Yes, to get the margin add 52px of margin to .flexnav.flexnav-show:

```
.flexnav.flexnav-show {
max-height: 2000px;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
margin-top: 52px; <-- HERE
}
```

To get the article to move down add padding to the first p. Add this to the lowest media query:

```
p:first-child {
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't see that it also effected the li items. But should I alter the margin for .menu-button to facilitate this of alter the margin for the .flexnav li item?
Furthermore I also need to effect the margin for #article to push it down on the lower media query only.

Comment: Thanks, the blog menu post is showing up in the menu and the article content is showing up as it should.
I still have a problem with the menu if I click it after scrolling down the page, it doesn't fold out until I scroll back up again to the top of the page.
I guess also that margin-top value should be lower for media queries above 480px

Comment: There's a way to do that by adding a class to the .flexnav class:  .flexnav{
position:fixed;
}

Comment: Thanks, that worked out :) But I need to compensate for the margin-top:52px; (so that the topmost li item Blogg shows up on the mobile) But for the iPad  @media all and (min-width: 800px) I wanted to put the margin-top:0px; (on line 638)or even -140px but this has no effect.